# Windows did not generate Debug Window when application crashed

Tags: windows, debugging, windows-xp, registry

When my application crashed, Windows XP did not generate the window given below
[image]

I configured the Just In Time (JIT) debugger as given below.Windows generated the above window when some other applications crashed.
What could be the problems?
Is there any mechanisms to know whether an application exited normally or crashed?

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AeDebug]
"Auto"="0"
"Debugger"="C:\NeST\DebuggingTools\Debugging Tools for Windows (x86)\ntsd.exe -p %ld -e %ld -g -noio -c ".dump /ma /u c:\dumps\jit.dmp; q"
"UserDebuggerHotKey"=dword:00000000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why this hasn't worked for you, but you can launch your app using [adPlus](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/286350). You're then not dependent on some global registry settings, and have more control about the monitoring.

Comment: When I attach adPlus, the application does not crash. So I configured NTSD for JIT debugging

Comment: @Maanu, does your app crash when there's no debugger attached, and run successfully when there is? If that seems to be the case, are you sure the debugger can write the dump file in the folder you've specified?

Comment: Windows shows the dialog box in some cases. But in some other cases it does not show the dialog box. When I click on the Debug, button of the dialog, it generates the dump file

Comment: @Maanu, just to be 100% sure: 1. when there's no message, can you tell if the app really crashed or not? 2. Is there enough space on your drive for the dump files? Dump size might change, leading to inconsistent results if the drive is full. BTW, adPlus uses CDB, which is similar to NTSD, but it eliminates the need for the system JIT setting, so there's one less place to make an error...